# What is wrong with this jQuery/Ajax function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an online chat room that uses jQuery/Ajax for requesting data from the server. However, the method I use is very inefficient and I'm trying to improve it by only loading the server data if the chat content has been changed (new message, etc.) The method seems to be logically correct, although somehow it never evaluates to true. I've attached the code below, please tell me what I'm doing wrong as this is giving me a very hard time. I want the chat div to be changed only when the data from the server is different.

```
function loadMsgs()
{
var v_loadMsgs = new XMLHttpRequest();

v_loadMsgs.open("GET", "msgs.php");

v_loadMsgs.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    var old_content = $("#msgs").html();
    var new_content = v_loadMsgs.responseText;

    if (old_content != new_content) 
    {
        $("#msgs").html(new_content);
    }

    if (old_content == new_content) 
    {
        $("#msgs").html("EQUAL!"); // only here for testing
    }
};

v_loadMsgs.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use jQuery's AJAX functions. They make everything really simple:

```
function loadMsgs()
{
    jQuery.get("msgs.php", function(data)
    {
        if ($("#msgs").html() != data) 
        {
            $("#msgs").html(data);
        } else {
            $("#msgs").html("EQUAL!"); // only here for testing
        }
    });
}
```

If you really want to know why your method isn't working, you're not checking if the server actually sent you a response (which returns a `readyState` of `4`):

```
function loadMsgs()
{
var v_loadMsgs = new XMLHttpRequest();

v_loadMsgs.open("GET", "msgs.php");

v_loadMsgs.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (v_loadMsgs.readyState == 4)
    {
        var old_content = $("#msgs").html();
        var new_content = v_loadMsgs.responseText;

        if (old_content != new_content) 
        {
            $("#msgs").html(new_content);
        }

        if (old_content == new_content) 
        {
            $("#msgs").html("EQUAL!"); // only here for testing
        }
    }
};

v_loadMsgs.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I'm going to look further into jQuery's built in Ajax functions, they seem really nice. Thanks a ton!

Comment: jQuery is filled with tons of useful functions ;) Mark one of the answers as the solution, if the answer answered your question. When you do, it helps other with the same problem find the solution more quickly.

Comment: Thanks, I just did that :) And thanks so much for pointing out my initial error, it was driving me crazy. I wasn't checking the readyState because I was under the impression that jQuery does that on its own, but I guess that was a bad misunderstanding!

Comment: jQuery *does* do it all on it's own, you were just re-inventing the wheel by writing AJAX requests from scratch. I'm not demoting that (I did this for a simple site, as I didn't need jQuery's selectors, animation, etc.), so if you really need it, I'd just drop jQuery altogether.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `.html()`, the browser gives you neatly formatted HTML. That is, all tags closed, all attributes in quotes, that sort of thing. And what you're returning from `msgs.php` is, most likely, not formatted perfectly. Hence, the difference.

If you're worried about inefficiency, however, this method would *still* be pretty inefficient. I mean, yes, you don't update the UI needlessly anymore, but you're still loading the list of messages from the server, don't you?

In order to save a couple of bytes here, you should rather have employed the "if-modified" technique. That is, along with the list of messages, return some kind of timestamp. Say, just an integer. When something changes on the server, increase that integer by one. When requesting an update from the server, have your AJAX code pass the previous received timestamp, and then have the server respond "nothing changed" if the timestamp is current. Otherwise, have the server transmit the new list of messages. This is, roughly, the idea.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that, thanks. It seems my best bet is to look into the jQuery.ajax() functions for something like this, I guess.

Comment: @user665132: see my update please. And by the way, using `jQuery.ajax` won't help you here at all.

Comment: I see what you're saying. That sounds like a good idea, as the reponseText is storing all the server-delivered data and constantly being emptied/reloaded with it. I'll definitely do that :)

Comment: You could try making a separate `check.php` file which outputs a `1` if you have received new data within a set interval, and nothing if you haven't. It would save you having to load data.

Answer (score 1):

try using [jquery's ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for an explanation as to why this isn't working. Is my implementation flawed, or is this method just not suitable?

Comment: what `always evaluates to true`?